# Messages not purging - discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for my Discord server I want it to it to purge x amount of messages after x amount of days automatically when the bot starts.

I'm currently using discord.py rewrite.

This is how I'm trying to do the aforementioned

```
async def on_ready(self):
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(494870373473583119)
        if channel:
            self.bot.loop.create_task(self.purge(channel)) 

async def purge(self, channel):
    while True:
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        days_to_delete = now - timedelta(days=0)
        await channel.purge(before=days_to_delete)
```

I've run this code through various changes to it and I'm unable to purge any messages. Could anyone tell me where I might be going wrong here. If you could break it down in an example or cite that would help.

Comment: Is this code in a cog?

Comment: yes the bot is modular

Comment: Do you have an `on_error` event that could be suppressing a meaningful error?  I just tested a very similar coroutine with a different channel id and `mesgs = await channel.purge(limit=5, before=days_to_delete)` `await channel.send("Deleted messages {}".format(" ".join(m.content for m in mesgs)))`, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I really I'm not sure I've check other events they seems to be working fine and I don't have an `on_error` event. The only event not work seems to be `on_ready`  I'm not sure if a listener is required

Comment: The issue turns out to be `before=two_weeks_ago` it seems that I'm importing timedelta this way `import datetime as dt` and `from datetime import timedelta` however still stuck on how to purge x amount of messages after x amount of days,

Comment: That should be `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `two_weeks_ago = now - timedelta(days=0)` this line to `two_weeks_ago = now - dt.timedelta(days=0)` or change the way you are importing `datetime` and `timedelta`.